# Python not able to put a variable in header "session-token"

Tags: python, request, http-headers

i'm working on winrest api and since my session token will change from time to time i would like to ad it in a variable, when run my code i get a return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)

here the code :

```
sessionToken = 'session_token': 'gggg6gsl68l2vdim5fgggggg'}
 
headers = {
   'App-Token': 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa',
   'Session-Token': sessionToken
}

response = requests.get(urlUnencryptedWorkstation, headers=headers)
```

Comment: The syntax for `sessionToken` is certainly off. Why is there a `:` and `}` do you want a nested dictionary? What error do you receive?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you're looking for:

```
import requests as req

urlUnencryptedWorkstation = 'https://www.google.com'  # Whatever the url is
sessionToken = 'gggg6gsl68l2vdim5fgggggg'

headers = {
    'App-Token': 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa',
    'Session-Token': sessionToken
}

res = req.get(urlUnencryptedWorkstation, headers=headers)
print(res.status_code, res.text)
```

Hope this helps :) Cheers!